# Determine License Type of Adobe Creative Suite # on Mac

Tags: macos, adobe

When Adobe Creative Suite 6 (or any other Creative Suite) is installed on Windows, you can list the installed programs and see the Creative Suite 6 Master Collection or Design Premium item in the list. So I can tell on Windows that I've either got the Design Premium or Master Collection or what have you.

On Mac, I simply can only get the installed products. Meaning I can only list each item: Photoshop, Illustrator, etc. What I've been doing currently is doing a binary flag for each product and checking that value against precompiled listings. Like so:

```
InDesign | Encore | Illustrator | Photoshop
   0     | 1      |  1          | 1            = 7, Means that They have the Production
   0     | 0      |  1          | 1            = 3, Means that They have the Design Premium
etc...
```

My implementation on this is complicated and riddled of bugs, so I was hoping there was an easier solution to this (Some kind of key->value setting or some file I can read to check for that only exists with certain license types).
Link to the Product Types: http://www.adobe.com/products/catalog/cs6._sl_id-contentfilter_sl_catalog_sl_software_sl_creativesuite6.html?start=10

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back, this probably isn't the best location for this question. I have however figured out an answer to it though.

If you look in /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Installers/ there is a symbolic link to some seemingly random named .app for the uninstaller. This link will contain the type of your suite. ie "Adobe Creative Suite 6 Master Collection", or "Adobe Creative Suite 6 Design and Web Premium". In the case of Adobe Creative Cloud, they simply have an uninstaller for each product. ie "Adobe Photoshop CC".

I did a bit more digging and inside the /Library/Application Support/Adobe/ssc/ there are folders with some XML configuration files. I'm sure with a bit more digging you will find out what versions you have a license for, maybe.

The solution above of searching for adobe installers however, works for me, and I hope it will help other users.